# How can I implement the Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

Using Extended Euclidean Algorithm:
I want the output to look like this:

```
algo(700,440) =   [20, -5, 8]
algo(88,35) =     [1, 2, -5]
algo(35,88) =     [1, -5, 2]
algo(-88,35) =    [1, 2, -5]
algo(88,-35) =    [1, 2, -5]
algo(0,777) =     Error(algo): Invalid input num
```

But I am getting this output:

```
#enter code here
algo(700,440) =   (20, -5, 8)
algo(88,35) =     (1, 2, -5)
algo(35,88) =     (1, -5, 2)
algo(-88,35) =    (-1, 2, 5)
algo(88,-35) =    (1, 2, 5)
algo(0,777) =     (777, 0, 1)
```

My code is:

```
def algo(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b,0,1) 
    else:
        g, y, x = algo(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)
```

I confused on how I can get my values into a list, and trouble printing an error message. Any time I change to a print statement in the first if case, I get an error. Function doesn't need to be recursive but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why you would want an error here; the HCF of 0 and 777 is indeed 777, and it can indeed be written as 0*0 + 1*777. The input is perfectly valid.

Comment: 1. Return [ ] instead of ( ) to get a list. 2. Looks like your base should be if a==1 instead of a==0, and if a==0 you want to raise an exception.

Comment: I can't raise an exception, I have to have a specific output. Any ideas as to why when I try to print the correct output I am getting -> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: The "too many values to unpack" error is because the line `g, y, x = algo(b % a, a)` expects `algo` to return three values, so if you return just one (an error message) instead, then it cannot assign values to all three variables. This is just one of many good reasons you should raise an exception instead of returning an error message. If you are not allowed to raise an exception due to some arbitrary constraint of the problem, this should have been written in the question.

Comment: I can raise an exception but It doesn't really help me fix the errors I get when my input has a 0

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to signal an error is to `raise` one, not to `return` an error message of some sort:

```py
def algo(a,b):
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        raise ValueError('HCF of 0, 0 is undefined')
    elif a == 0:
        return [b, 0, 1] 
    else:
        g, y, x = algo(b % a, a)
        return [g, x - (b // a) * y, y]
```

To handle this in your other code, use `try`/`except`:

```py
pairs = [(700, 440), (88, 35), (35, 88), (-88, 35), (88, -35), (0, 0), (0, 777)]

for a, b in pairs:
    try:
        r = algo(a, b)
        print('algo({0}, {1}) = {2}'.format(a, b, r))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
algo(700, 440) = [20, -5, 8]
algo(88, 35) = [1, 2, -5]
algo(35, 88) = [1, -5, 2]
algo(-88, 35) = [-1, 2, 5]
algo(88, -35) = [1, 2, 5]
HCF of 0, 0 is undefined
algo(0, 777) = [777, 0, 1]
```

Note that the highest common factor is well-defined when one number is zero; the input is only really invalid when both numbers are zero.

Comment: I think he wants the result to be a list and not a tuple.

Comment: It's possible to signal an error whenever you want to; but the question asks how to implement the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, for which (0, 777) is *not* an invalid input. The output [777, 0, 1] is correct.

Comment: @Lizzy if you really want to raise the exception to match your desired output, just modify kaya3's code: change `if a == 0 and b == 0 raise...:` to `if a == 0: raise...` and see if that works.

Comment: It won't work, because `a == 0` is the base case of the recursion, of course.

Comment: If you absolutely must have a function which behaves a certain way (for the purpose of a homework problem), write a separate function which returns an error message as a string when `a == 0`, and otherwise calls the proper algorithm and returns the result of that.

Comment: Any time I return something that doesn't follow (#,#,#) format I get an error or do you mean create a whole new function?

Comment: Your `algo` function is recursive and cannot signal an error on `a == 0` because that is the base case of the recursion; it will break your algorithm however you signal an error, because every valid input is reduced recursively to the case `a == 0`, so that case needs to be handled by returning the correct answer, not by signalling an error. So yes, you must write a separate function if you want a function which signals an error when `a == 0`, because `algo` cannot do this without breaking it for all inputs.